# Neural network with both input and output of model are matrices

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm a beginner at Keras. I want to create a multi-perceptron model (Dense layer) with input is a 10x4 matrix and output is a 5x4 matrix. I can use input_shape = (10,4) for input but how about output? Please help me out

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', name='layer1', input_shape = (10,4)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', name='layer2'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', name='layer3'))
...?
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the input Matrix? Is the first dimension corresponding to the Batch size? If so, the input shape of the dense layer should be declared as follows:

```py
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', name='layer1', input_shape = (4,)))
```

Keras takes care of batch dimension for you.

Otherwise, if you input has 3 dimensions (BATCH, TIMESTEPS, FEATURES) you should go with RNN or Conv1d.

Also, since you end up your Sequential model with a `Dense(8)` your output will have this shape: (BATCH, 8).

If you think that going with RNN is to complex or there is no need to do so, you can flat your input as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

inp_tensor = np.random.uniform(size=(5, 10, 4)) # Batch size 5 and your input matrix
inp_tensor = inp_tensor.reshape(5, -1) # Now tensor has shape (5, 10 * 4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', name='layer1', input_shape = (10 * 4,)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', name='layer2'))
# Note that the output is 5 * 4, which corresponds to the desired output shape (5, 4) but flattened 
model.add(Dense(5 * 4, activation='relu', name='layer3'))

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

# At inference time, we do the same
test_inp = np.random.uniform(size=(1, 10, 4)) # A single instance
pred = model.predict(test_inp.reshape(1, -1)

# Recover your desired output shape
pred = pred.reshape(1, 5, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My input and output are really matrices, and the batch size is not cared. According to your answer, the matrix must be reshaped to a vector in the multi-perceptron case. The input can be a matrix in RNN or CNN case. Am I right?